# How to get temporary persistent credentials accessing google applications by Java Code

Tags: java, google-api, google-drive-api, google-oauth, google-sheets-api

I'm on practice with google drive/sheets/oauth API Java for a standalone application.

My focus is now on client authentication.
I registered my application on google developer console and got the client json file.

So, following [the tutorial](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/java), this is the Authentication snippet of code

```
/** Directory to store user credentials for this application. */

private static final java.io.File DATA_STORE_DIR = ResourceLoader.googleCredentials();

/** Global instance of the {@link FileDataStoreFactory}. */
private static DataStoreFactory DATA_STORE_FACTORY;

/** Global instance of the JSON factory. */
private static final JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();

/** Global instance of the HTTP transport. */
private static HttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT;

/** Global instance of the scopes required by this quickstart.
 *
 * If modifying these scopes, delete your previously saved credentials
 * at ~/.credentials/drive-java-quickstart
 */
private static final List<String> SCOPES =
    Arrays.asList(DriveScopes.DRIVE); 

static {
    try {
        HTTP_TRANSPORT = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
        DATA_STORE_FACTORY = new FileDataStoreFactory(DATA_STORE_DIR);
    } catch (Throwable t) {
        MyLogger.getLogger().severe(t);
    }
}


/**
 * Creates an authorized Credential object.
 * @return an authorized Credential object.
 * @throws IOException
 */
private Credential authorize() throws IOException {
    // Load client secrets.
    //InputStream in = GDriveQuickStart.class.getResourceAsStream("/client_secret.json");

    Credential credential = null;

        InputStream in = new FileInputStream(ResourceWorking.googleClientSecretPath());

        GoogleClientSecrets clientSecrets = GoogleClientSecrets.load(JSON_FACTORY, new InputStreamReader(in));

        MyLogger.getLogger().info(clientSecrets.getDetails().toPrettyString());

        // Build flow and trigger user authorization request.
        GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow =
                new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, clientSecrets, SCOPES)
                .setDataStoreFactory(DATA_STORE_FACTORY)
                .setAccessType("offline")
                .build();
        credential = new AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(flow, new LocalServerReceiver()).authorize("user");

        MyLogger.getLogger().info(credential.getAccessToken()+" "+credential.getRefreshToken()+" "+credential.getExpirationTimeMilliseconds()+" "+credential.getExpiresInSeconds());

    return credential;
}
```

When the application runs for the first time, it opens a browser page for the authentication by google user and acceptance of terms of condition.
Then, the credentials are saved into the folder identified by `DATA_STORE_DIR (tipically .credentials/StoredCredential binary file).

In this way, running again the application avoid the browser page opening: you are always authenticated.

So, I would that this `Stored Credentials` had an expiration time and so, after, for example, one month, the browser page opens again and the `Stored Credential` will be overrided.

Check the last log line: the access token has a life of only one hour but when it expires it refresh automatically.

The only way I've found is using the `MemoryDataStoreFactory` instead of `FileDataStoreFactory` but in this way every time the application runs it opens the browser page.

So, is there a way by `Google API` to obtain temporary `Stored Credential`?

I explain why I want it: the application will be used by different users. I want to avoid the critical case that would happen whent a user copies the application folder and give it to another user. The credential folder is into the application folder and so he will copy the `StoredCredential` file too. The new user so will use the application with the old user authentication.

Comment: You should be able to tell FileDataStoreFactory where to store the credentials.  https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-http-java-client/reference/1.19.0/com/google/api/client/util/store/FileDataStoreFactory

Comment: Yes I'm able to. What's that to do with what I asked?

Comment: ok, understood. I colud put the folder outside the application, It's an option that I would avoid

Answer (score 1):

> I explain why I want it: the application will be used by different users. I want to avoid the critical case that would happen whent a user copies the application folder and give it to another user. The credential folder is into the application folder and so he will copy the StoredCredential file too. The new user so will use the application with the old user authentication.

This is actually very important you dont want to take the chance of leaking user information.  However you also need to consider that you cant protect yourself from everything stupid users will do.

The .Net Client Library defaults FileDataStore saving to %appdata% for this very reason.   The Java client library and the .net Client libraries are designed quite similar thats how i can help a bit with this.

What you need to do is just store your credentials out side your main application folder I am not sure what system you are running on but %appdata% works well for windows.  THis way if the user does copy the directory they wont by chance copy your credeintals files.

Another option would be to make your own implementation of the data store and maybe add some kind of check so that when they are created use the mac address of the machine and only load them if its the same machine.   This is a bit over kill if you ask me.

Comment: I would prefer a temporary StoredCredential solution.

But by now, I choose your solution.

So,
    
private static final java.io.File DATA_STORE_DIR = new File(System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir")); //ResourceLoader.googleCredentials();